# How do I get specific data from this Json data?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have the following JSON data

```
    {
    "results": [
        {
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "confidence": 0.6,
                    "transcript": "state radio "
                }
            ],
            "final": true
        },
        {
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "confidence": 0.77,
                    "transcript": "tomorrow I'm headed to mine nine 
    consecutive big con I'm finna old tomorrow I've got may meet and greet 
    with whoever's dumb enough to line up "
                }
            ],
            "final": true
```

If I try `data["results"]`, it works and I get everything inside "results".

But if I try `data["alternatives"]`, it doesn't work.

I want to get the text in "transcript", how can I get that?

Comment: `data['results'][<index>]['alternatives']['transcript']` since result is a list so to get alternatives you need to reference the index

Answer (score 1):

`"transcripts"` is not a direct child of `data`. It is, instead, the child of element `"alternatives"`, which is a child of each element of the list `"results"`, which is, in turn, the  direct child of `data`. So, to get your contents of transcript as a list, do:

```py
transcripts = [r["alternatives"]["transcript"] for r in data["results"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To access alternatives,

```
data['results'][0]['alternatives']['transcript]
```

change the index 0,1,2,3 ... according to which transcript data you need to extract.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected result by using the code:

```
import json
d='''
    {
    "results": [
        {
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "confidence": 0.6,
                    "transcript": "state radio "
                }
            ],
            "final": true
        },
        {
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "confidence": 0.77,
                    "transcript": "tomorrow I'm headed to mine nine consecutive big con I'm finna old tomorrow I've got may meet and greet with whoever's dumb enough to line up "
                }
            ],
            "final": true
        }
    ]}
'''
data = json.loads(d)
for i in range(len(data['results'])):
    transcript=data['results'][i]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
    print(transcript)
```